# snowflake sso connection using sqlalchemy does not work

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i am trying to configure an sso connection in my python script.
here's my code:

```
import sqlalchemy
def get_snowflake_engine(warehouse="ETL", environment=None):
    username = ‘userx@domainx.com'
    account = ‘accountx
    database = ‘dbx’
    authenticator = 'externalbrowser'
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        f"snowflake://{username}:@{account}/{database}?authenticator={authenticator}&warehouse={warehouse}"
    )

engine = get_snowflake_engine(environment='production')
connection = engine.connect()
try:
    result = connection.execute('SELECT NOW()').fetchall()
    print(result)
finally:
    connection.close()
    engine.dispose()
```

i expect my browser to pop with an authorisation form (we use google for sso)
and i get a messeage on the terminal, but nothing happens on the browser:

```
Initiating login request with your identity provider. A browser window should have opened for you to complete the login. If you can't see it, check existing browser windows, or your OS settings. Press CTRL+C to abort and try again...
```

after a while i get an exception

any advice?
using MacOS, Pycharm

BTW i configured on DataGrip a connection using authenticator = 'externalbrowser' and it works as expected.

TIA

Comment: What is the exception you get? Does it have an error code under the form 25XXXX?

Comment: `snowflake.connector.errors.ForbiddenError: HTTP 403: Forbidden`
but after a long time that the message is hanging:

`Initiating login request with your identity provider. A browser window should have opened for you to complete the login. If you can't see it, check existing browser windows, or your OS settings. Press CTRL+C to abort and try again...`

Comment: That sounds like a network issue to me (either on the path or on the cloud provider). Is is still reproducible? What about collecting generating the connector [logs](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors) and see if they provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the connector logs showed that it was missing the AWS region in the connection URL (eu-west-1 in my case) so I fixed by adding:

```
...
region = 'eu-west-1'
...
return sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    f"snowflake://{username}:@{account}.{region}/{database}?authenticator={authenticator}&warehouse={warehouse}"
)
```

This resulted in the browser authentication window opening in browser and the query returning successfully.